# Flask-Appbuilder POST from form None

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms, flask-appbuilder

My POST sends the data of the RadioField that was chosen, but in Flask I only get 'None' for the `form.display.data` . The GET works fine, and RadioFields are on the page, when I click 'Submit' the display variable is sent in POST with the correct choice.

How do I get the actual data for the POST?

**views.py**

```
class Items(SimpleFormView):
    route_base = "/manage"
    datamodel = SQLAInterface(TerminalA82)
    message = "Please make a seslection"
    form = List_Items()

    myList = Controller.generate #<-- external function provides list
    form.display.choices = myList

    @expose('/manage', methods=['GET'])
    @has_access
    def this_form_get(self):
        return self.render_template('list_items.html', param1='Items', form=self.form)

    @expose('/manage', methods=['POST'])
    @has_access
    def this_form_post(self):
        return self.render_template('blank.html', param1=str(self.form.display.data))
```

The POST renders 'None' on the page.

**forms.py**

```
class List_Items(Form):
    display = RadioField('Items', choices=[], coerce=int)
```

**list_items.html (Template)**

```
{% extends "appbuilder/base.html" %}
{% block content %}
<h3>{{param1}}</h3>
<form method="post">
    {{ form.display }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

**myList content**

```
>>> print myList
[('5', 'MyBAsic'), ('9', 'Cloudtest'), ('12', 'Test2'), ('15', 'NHLS-Test'), ('18', 'HSRC-Test')]
>>>
```

**blank.html**

```
{% extends "appbuilder/base.html" %}
{% block content %}
    <p>{{param1}}</p>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: print myList and paste blank.html. I think you need to read it as request.form['Items']

Comment: I included the contents of `myList` and `blank.html` too in the post above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if you see flask documentation then you need to access that piece of data as `request.form['Items']` not as `form.display.data`.

Comment: When I change to `self.request.form['Items']` I get 
`AttributeError: 'Item' object has no attribute 'request'`

Comment: no request is not part of Item object which would be instance of class Items. Just try request.form['Items']. Request object is passed by flask to views.

Comment: if I change to just `request.form['Items']` then I get `NameError: global name 'request' is not defined`

Comment: You need to say from `flask import request` on top of your file. I would advice you to use base flask first and get used to it before trying Appbuilder.

Comment: Yes I just spotted that. Thanks. I managed to resolve it. I had to do `request.form['display']` and not `['Items']`. Now I get the value. Thanks for your help

Comment: Sorry about that mistake. Of course the field name is `display`. Please read flask documentation. It is a very nice one and will help you a lot.